# Where Column like '%__2017%' is returning columns with _2017

Tags: t-sql

I have a table with a number of file names that have a date time stamp added to the file name. Unfortunately the process for creating the filenames is not consistent so I end up with names like,

```
RandomFilename__20170622_013633.csv
Some_other_Filename__20170621_015423.csv
YET-Another-Filename_20170605_010005.csv
```

Eventually I would like a select statement I would like to strip out the characters after filename and before the _timestamp and __timestamp. Ideally my select statement would remove the unwanted characters using LEFT() and CHARINDEX().

The below query is returning unexpected results

```
SELECT [Name]
FROM FileList    
WHERE NAME like '%__2017%'
```

I get filenames with just a single underscore as well. This is throwing off my charindex for '__2017' and '_2017'.

Here is the current query I'm using to try and strip out the unwanted timestamp characters from the name column.

```
SELECT top 100 [Name]
  ,CASE 
    WHEN NAME like '%__2017%' then LEFT(NAME,CHARINDEX('_201',name) - 2)
    WHEN NAME like '%_2017%' then LEFT(NAME,CHARINDEX('_201',name) - 1)
  END AS ShortName
FROM [dbo].[FilesHistory]
```

Unfortunately this strips the filenames with a single underscore by 1 character too many, i.e. YET-Another-Filenam

Comment: `_` is also a reserved character in `LIKE` patterns. You need to escape it.

Comment: What about if the filename has 2017 in the filename? i.e. Yearly_Profit_2017_20170622_013633.csv

Comment: The filename will never have 2017 in it.

Comment: @Dai That appears to have been my problem. After using LIKE '%[_][_]2017%', I started getting my expected results.  Thanks.

Comment: @GeoffDawdy You need to escape the underscores in your Markdown comment, it caused the square-brackets to be rendered in italics. I think you mean `LIKE '%[_][_]2017%'`.